# Finding items that are common to all the input files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a series of files of the type-

```
f1.txt     f2.txt    f3.txt
A          B         A
B          G         B
C          H         C
D          I         E
E          L         G
F          M         J
```

I want to find out the entries that are common to all three files. In this case the expected output would be `B` since that is the only letter that occurs is all three files.

If I had just two files, I could find out the common entries using `comm -1 -2 f1.txt f2.txt`.

But that doesn't work with multiple files. I thought about something like

`sort -u f*.txt > index     #to give me the total unique entries`

`while read i ; do *test if entry is present in all the files* ; done < index`

I thought of iteratively doing the `comm -12 f1.txt f2.txt | comm -12 - f3.txt`  but I have 100+ files so that's not practical. Performance does matter.

**EDIT**

I implemented the following-

```
sort -u f* > index

while read i 
do 
   echo -n "$i " 
   grep -c "$i" f*.txt > temp 
   awk -F ":" '{a+=$2} END {print a}' temp 
done < index | sort -rnk2
```

This gives the output-

```
B 3
G 2
E 2
C 2
A 2
M 1
L 1
J 1
I 1
H 1
F 1
D 1
```

From here I can see that the number of files is 3 and the occurrence of `B` is 3. Hence it occurs in all the files. I'm still looking for a better solution though.

Comment: that while loop can be shortened: `sort f* | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Comment: Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (i in cnt) if (cnt[i]==(ARGC-1)) print i}' *.txt
```

The above assumes each value occurs no more than once in a given file, like in your example. If a value CAN occur multiple times in one file then:

```
awk '!seen[FILENAME,$0]++{cnt[$0]++} END{for (i in cnt) if (cnt[i]==(ARGC-1)) print i}' *.txt
```

or with GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and ARGIND:

```
awk '{cnt[$0][ARGIND]} END{for (i in cnt) if (length(cnt[i])==ARGIND) print i}' *.txt
```

Comment: My files will never have repetitions in them so your first answer was good enough. But always good to have the more general solution. Thanks so much! I'm waiting for some more solutions (though nothing is going to beat this) and then I'll 'accept' your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using python

This python script with find the common lines among a large number of files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from glob import glob
fnames = glob('f*.txt')
with open(fnames[0]) as f:
    lines = set(f.readlines())
for fname in fnames[1:]:
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = lines.intersection(f.readlines())
print(''.join(lines))
```

Sample run:

```
$ python script.py
B
```

How it works:

- `fnames = glob('f*.txt')`

  This collects the names of files of interest.
- `with open(fnames[0]) as f:
      lines = set(f.readlines())`

  This reads the first file and creates a *set* from its lines.  This set is called `lines`.
- `for fname in fnames[1:]:
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = lines.intersection(f.readlines())`

  For each subsequent file, this takes the intersection of `lines` with the lines of this file.
- `print(''.join(lines))`

  This prints out the resulting set of common lines.

#### Using grep and shell

Try:

```
$ grep -Ff f1.txt f2.txt | grep -Ff f3.txt
B
```

This works in two steps:

1. `grep -Ff f1.txt f2.txt` selects those lines from f2.txt that also occur in f1.txt.  In other words, the output from this command consists of lines that f1.txt and f2.txt have in common.
2. `grep -Ff f3.txt` selects from its input all lines that are also in f3.txt.

Notes:

- The `-F` option tells grep to treat its input as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
- The `-f` option tells grep to get the patterns it is looking for from the file whose name follows.
- The command above looks for complete matching lines.  That means, for one, that leading or trailing white space is significant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @John1024. This works but I already had a similar solution in my answer (Look at the last sentence of the question). I'm looking for a way to loop over all the files (100+ input files). Can this solution of yours be extended?

Comment: @VarunM I just added to the answer a python script that handles an arbitrarily large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Ed's answer is considerably faster than my suggestion, but I'll leave it for posterity :-)

I used **GNU Parallel** to apply `comm` to the files in pairs in parallel (so it should be fast) and do that repeatedly, passing the output of each iteration as the input to the next.

It converges when there is only one file left to process. If there are an odd number of files at any stage, the odd file is promoted forward to the next round and processed later.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
# Get list of files
files=(f*.txt)
iter=0
while : ; do
   # Get number of files
   n=${#files[@]}
   echo DEBUG: Iter: $iter, Files: $n
   # If only one file left, we have converged, cat it and exit
   [ $n -eq 1 ] && { cat ${files[0]}; break; }
   # Check if odd number of files, and promote and delete one if odd
   if (( n % 2 )); then
      mv ${files[0]} s-$iter-odd;
      files=( ${files[@]:1} )
   fi
   parallel -n2 comm -1 -2 {1} {2} \> s-$iter-{#} ::: "${files[@]}"
   files=(s-$iter-*)
   (( iter=iter+1 ))
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: Iter: 0, Files: 110
DEBUG: Iter: 1, Files: 55
DEBUG: Iter: 2, Files: 28
DEBUG: Iter: 3, Files: 14
DEBUG: Iter: 4, Files: 7
DEBUG: Iter: 5, Files: 4
DEBUG: Iter: 6, Files: 2
DEBUG: Iter: 7, Files: 1
```

Basically, `s-0-*` is the output of the first pass, `s-1-*` is the output of the second pass...

If you would like to see the commands `parallel` would run, without it actually running any of them, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`:

```
$ join f1.txt <(join f2.txt f3.txt)
B
```

`join` expects the files to be sorted, though. This seems to work too:

```
$ join <(sort f1.txt) <(join <(sort f2.txt) <(sort f3.txt))
B
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. But again, it gets unwieldy for a large number of files. But I didn't know this could be done with join, so that's nice!

Answer (score 0):

If (but only if) all of your files have unique entries this should work too:

`sort f*.txt | uniq -c \
| grep "^\s*$(ls f*.txt | wc -w)\s" \
| while read n content; do echo $content; done`